# How Django processes a request when matched regular expression returned no named groups?

Tags: django, django-urls

I have read the documentation of django, specifically about HTTP/URL. I have found information about how Django processes a request [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/), which says:

> If the matched regular expression returned no named groups, then the matches from the regular expression are provided as positional arguments.

I can't understand what happens when the regular expression returns no named groups (like "").

Comment: Your example of '"' is odd. Do you understand what it means for a regular expression match to turn named groups?

Comment: The [first example in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/#example) has non-named groups, and the [named groups section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/#named-groups) below has named groups.